# How do I format the iOS 7 UIPickerView to display only 3 choices? I.e. One above and one below the active choice?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I want to format the iOS 7 UIPickerView to display only three choices. I.e. one above and one below the selected option. I would also like to format the text to be smaller than the default. How do I achieve this?

Comment: One way to go would be to put it in a view make it shorter on both ends and enable clip subviews but I feel there must be a better way to achieve this.

Comment: You could manipulate it on first load using:     [pickerView selectRow:1 inComponent:0 animated:NO];

Comment: @CW0007007 I didn't get it. I don't want to select a particular row. I want to display 3 instead of the default five selection options and format the font size.

Comment: Oh I see. How are you creating it ? You just load it with a datasource containing three objects surely. - See my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementing these delegate methods will give you a picker view with 3 rows and let you customise the font, colour etc...

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
        return 1;
    }

    - (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {

        UILabel *pickerRowLabel = (UILabel *)view;

        if (pickerRowLabel == nil) {
            CGRect frame = //YOUR PICKERVIEW FRAME. HEIGHT IS 44 by default.
            pickerRowLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
           //FORMAT THE FONT FOR THE LABEL AS YOU LIKE
            pickerRowLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            pickerRowLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        }

        pickerRowLabel.text = //YOUR TEXT, MOST LIKELY FROM AN ARRAY ... ?

        return pickerRowLabel;
    }

    - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

        return 3; //MOST LIKELY YOUR ARRAY OF OBJECTS COUNT
    }
```

Comment: actually there are more items than 3 in the array... I just want to display 3 so that I can make it shorter in height. i.e. 3 at a time... By default it displays five... 2 above and two below the selected row.

Comment: i was able to get it down to 3 item displaying by putting it in a view, shortening the view and clipping subviews of the view. Also the formatting worked as described by you so I am marking this as the answer. Thanks :)